# Solution of the LP relaxation - always round to the nearest integer?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

If an optimal solution to the LP relaxation of an IP is not integer, can we always get a feasible IP solution by rounding it to the nearest integer? Or can we generalize this process by saying, if we have a minimization problem, round it up; if it is a maximization problem, round it down and it will be feasible for the IP. Thanks.

Comment: If it were that simple, IP wouldn't be so much more expensive to perform than LP.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly trivial to construct a linear program with no feasible integer solution, so the answer to your question as stated would be no.